# Launching Applet on Glassfish 4

Tags: java, ssl, applet, glassfish

So I've written up an applet and am testing it on a locally hosted Glassfish server.I've deployed my jar but when I launch the applet it blocks it saying.

"There is a problem with the website's security certificate"

When I tell it to go forward with it anyway, it loads up java and runs for a while before asking me weather I want to continue.

"Do you want to Continue?"
"Website: 660-5nxcvn1:8181"

But the certificate it's looking for is "localhost" since that is where the domain is running.

It will tell me I do not have the permissions to run the applet and that I should change the settings in the Java Control panel. The setting is unalterable on my work computer and the option is unavailable.

I have tried adding a self signed certificate to the keystore created by glassfish, but without any change. I've read through the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3671/ablnk/index.html, as it was given in response to a similar question but I do not understand the application to the problem. Has anyone done something like this before and could perhaps outline the process?

Comment: Is your applet signed?

Comment: Now that I'm looking at documentation for signing it. I believe it is not. First applet. I will do that now.

Comment: I've got a self signed certificated that I am using to sign it. What applet files do I need to use for the bundling? Netbeans creates an executable JAR file, should I sign that? Or should I bundle up the build files in JAR and sign that?

When I try to 'jarsigner' the following C:\stuff here\openfile.jar test      test being the certificate

I get attempt to rename C:\stuff here\openfile.jar to C:\stuff her\openfile.jar.orig failed.

Comment: I would bundle all the files into the JAR file and sign it

Comment: I bundled the project folder into a .jar file using the jar command. Then signed it with the jarsigner. Went to deploy it using glassfish, but it did not recognize the "Archive type" Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applet never really worked when I used the signer. Instead I just moved the applet into the file structure of the domain on my computer. Ran it from there, and worked. If anyone has a problem like this in the future, I would advice this as opposed to fighting with glassfish.